# Find item in list and add to other list

Tags: elm

I have a model containing a list of items that are rendered in a `select` as options.
The user can select an item, enter a number and click add to add the selected item and a "quantity" to a list.

My model looks like this:

```
type alias Drink =
  { id: String
  , name: String
  }

type alias Item =
  { id: String
  , quantity: Int
  }

type alias Model =
  { drinks: List Drink
  , selected: List Item
  , inputDrink: String
  , inputQuantity: Int
  }
```

I then want to render the `selected` list in a table. My main struggle right now is figuring out how I map over the array of selected items, based on the id of the current item find the name of the `Drink` to render in the table.

I've made this `itemRow` view:

```
itemRow : (Item, Drink) -> Html Msg
itemRow tuple =
  -- This bit not updated to work with a Tuple yet.
  tr [ id item.id ]
    [ td []
      [ button [] [ text "x" ]
      ]
    , td [] [ text drink.name ]
    , td []
      [ input [ type_ "number", value (String.fromInt item.quantity) ] []
      ]
    ]
```

So what I'd like is to do something like:

```
model.selected
|> List.map (\selected -> (selected, List.Extra.find (\drink -> drink.id == selected.id)) )
|> List.map itemRow
```

But to do this I need to get rid of the `Maybe` I get from `List.Extra.find` and I don't know how…

Any other tips or tricks on how I might better solve this by modelling the data differently very welcome. New to Elm :)

Comment: The entire thing in its current form can be found here https://gist.github.com/simme/7520286b39231c8fd2661108038a18ec

Comment: You need to handle the cases where Maybe returns no value. Basically as I understood, in your case there'll always be a value since `selected` is subset of `drinks`. Hence you could use `Maybe.withDefault` or similar structure and simply ignore the case.

Comment: "I need to get rid of the Maybe I get from List.Extra.find". Have you tried appliying `List.filtermMap`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you remove the `Nothing`s. Although you know that the find must always succeed, Elm requires you to handle the case where it does not. Here I just ignore those cases.

```
model.selected
  |> List.filterMap (\selected -> 
    case List.Extra.find (\drink -> drink.id == selected.id) of 
      Just x -> Just (selected, x)
      Nothing -> Nothing 
    )
  |> List.map itemRow
```